# Draw a special shape on android canvas

Tags: java, android, drawing, android-canvas

I am struggling to draw this shape on an android canvas. I already used all what one could find in here. but it works on some angles and not on others.

[image]

Let's say that this shape can be drawn given a certain angle (in the example = 90°) 
We also have the coordinates of the three points of the shape (A,B and C)

Here is the code I currently use :

```
     // (cx,cy) is the point A 
     // (pos2LegX, pos2LegY) is the point C 
     // radDirection is the drawn example 90° 
     float radDirection = (float) (Math.toRadians(this.rad));
     float pos2LegX = (float) (cx + radius * Math.sin(radDirection)) ;
     float pos2LegY = (float) (cy - radius * Math.cos(radDirection)) ;

     // (arcPosX, arcPosY) is the point B
     float arcPosX = pos2LegX + (float) ((radius/2) * Math.abs(Math.cos(radDirection))) ;
     float arcPosY = pos2LegY - (float) ((radius/2) * Math.abs(Math.sin(radDirection))) ;

     // the rect to use with the drawers
     final RectF oval = new RectF();
     oval.set(pos2LegX , pos2LegY - radius/4, pos2LegX + radius/2, pos2LegY+ radius/4);

     // draw the shape 
     // draw AC
     canvas.drawLine(cx,cy,pos2LegX, pos2LegY ,paint);

     // draw the arc CB
     int startAngle = (int) (180 / Math.PI * Math.atan2(arcPosY - pos2LegY, arcPosX - pos2LegX));
     canvas.drawArc(oval,startAngle,180,false,paint);

     // draw BA
     canvas.drawLine(arcPosX,arcPosY,cx,cy,paint);
```

This may work for example if radDirection = 180 but if radDirection = 000 it gives this : 
[image]

But here, the shape should be in opposite direction with arc concave to the center cx, cy.

Any solution would be a big help for me.

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: What doesn't work in other angles exactly, and what are those angles? Can you share the you currently use for drawing the shape?

Comment: Thanks for answering Nicolas. I edited the original post :)

Comment: Is the curve between B and C arc of an exact circle?

Comment: It should be half a circle :)